# Adding addition field in Django rest framework modelserializer (write_only && read_write) in mixin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create a mixin for additional fields in Modelserializer.
Please refer the code below

```
class AdditionalFieldsMixin(object):
    additional_fields = dict()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdditionalFieldsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field_name, field_instance in self.additional_fields.items():
            self.fields[field_name] = field_instance
        print(self.fields)

    def additional_field_before_create(self, additional_field_data):
        pass

    def additional_field_after_create(self, additional_field_data, instance):
        pass

    def additional_field_before_update(self, additional_field_data):
        pass

    def additional_field_after_update(self, additional_field_data, instance):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        additional_field_data = {}

        for additional_field in self.additional_fields.keys():
            additional_field_data[additional_field] = validated_data.pop(additional_field, None)

        self.additional_field_before_create(additional_field_data)
        instance = super(AdditionalFieldsMixin, self).create(validated_data)
        self.additional_field_after_create(additional_field_data, instance)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        additional_field_data = {}

        for additional_field in self.additional_fields.keys():
            additional_field_data[additional_field] = validated_data.pop(additional_field, None)

        self.additional_field_before_update(additional_field_data)
        instance = super(AdditionalFieldsMixin, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        self.additional_field_after_update(additional_field_data, instance)
        return instance
```

In main class I declared

```
additional_fields = dict(
        reference=CharField(write_only=True, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, default=None),
    )
```

but when retrieving the data in list mode the it gives me an error

```
AssertionError: It is redundant to specify `source='reference'` on field 'CharField' in serializer 'MySerializer', because it is the same as the field name. Remove the `source` keyword argument.
```

why this is happening ?
also i noted that after starting runserver first time it doesn't give that error but if I query again it gives error second time and so on.

and another general question

what is the proper way to add fields in seialiser mixin class ?
i.e self.fields[field_name] = field_instance is right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extra read and write fields on Modelserializer**

The extra read and write fields must be derived from model instance so you can add `@property` or `def reference` on model and declare field on serializer as

```
reference = CharField(source='reference')
```

and pop the field data from validated data overriding create update of modelserializer.

In short, extra read and write field is very difficult to implement in straight forward code, **BUT IT IS POSSIBLE.**

**Extra read only fields on Modelserializer**

Use the `SerializerMethodField`, `ReadOnlyField` with `source` argument or similar to above code with `read_only=True` argument. e.g

```
reference = CharField(source='reference', read_only=True)
```

**Extra write only fields on Modelserializer** (Required Answer)

Writing field on mainserializer as

```
reference = CharField(write_only=True)
```

is fine the field will show in validated data in `create` and `update` so
override them, pop the field, do what you what to do with it, make `super()` call with new validated data.

**Make a mixin as asked in question** (for write only fields)

Turns out you can override the `to_internal_value` method of serializer and add fields to it. the `to_internal_value` is called when the serializer is saving data (creating, updating) so you can override it as follows

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    for field_name, field_instance in self.additional_write_only_fields.items():
        self.fields[field_name] = field_instance
    return super(AdditionalWriteOnlyFieldsMixin, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

this would solve the problem of adding many write only fields to model serializer. thats why I created the mixin as follows

```
class AdditionalWriteOnlyFieldsMixin(object):
    additional_write_only_fields = dict()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        for field_name, field_instance in self.additional_write_only_fields.items():
            self.fields[field_name] = field_instance
        return super(AdditionalWriteOnlyFieldsMixin, self).to_internal_value(data)

    def additional_fields_before_create(self, additional_data):
        pass

    def additional_fields_after_create(self, additional_data, instance):
        pass

    def additional_fields_before_update(self, additional_data):
        pass

    def additional_fields_after_update(self, additional_data, instance):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        additional_data = {key: validated_data.pop(key, None) for key in self.additional_write_only_fields.keys()}
        self.additional_fields_before_create(additional_data)
        instance = super(AdditionalWriteOnlyFieldsMixin, self).create(validated_data)
        self.additional_fields_after_create(additional_data, instance)
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        additional_data = {key: validated_data.pop(key, None) for key in self.additional_write_only_fields.keys()}
        self.additional_fields_before_update(additional_data)
        instance = super(AdditionalWriteOnlyFieldsMixin, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        self.additional_fields_after_update(additional_data, instance)
        return instance
```

So include the mixin in your modelserializer class and declare the `additional_write_only_fields` as dict with key as field name and value as field instance and override `additional_fields_*` function to implement your desired functionality e.g.

```
class MySerializer(AdditionalWriteOnlyFieldsMixin, ModelSerializer):
    additional_write_only_fields = dict(
        reference=CharField(write_only=True, allow_blank=True, allow_null=True, default=None),
    )
    
    def additional_fields_after_create(self, additional_data, instance):
        print(additional_data)
        
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        fields='__all__'
```

**Additional Notes**

You can also override the `to_representation` method of the serializer for adding read only fields or make a combination of `to_representation` and `to_internal_value` to make additional read write field!. but I leave this job for another answer-er.

**References**

- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior
- https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#core-arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, because if you use a modelerializer you can't request

```
class Name(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    ...
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```